# Login system doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a problem with my login script. The problem is, that the login scipt is supposed to check if the password and name is correct. If they are, then a site with informations should open.

The site does open, but the problem is, that no matter what password or name I type the page that is supposed to need correct password and a correct name opens.

And I can't find any errors in my script. Maybe you can help? Here are the scripts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
    .fehler { color: red; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    if (isset($_GET["f"]) && $_GET["f"] == 1) {
        echo "<p class='fehler'>Login-Daten nicht korrekt</p>";
    }

    ?>
    <form method="post" action="new 2.php">
        Your name, m'lady: <br />
        <input type="text" name="name" size="20" />
        <br />
        Your password, m'lady: <br />
        <input type="password" name="passwort" size="20" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

new 2.php script:

```
<?php

session_start();
$host  = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
$uri   = rtrim(dirname(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])), "/\\");    

if (isset($_POST["name"]) && $_POST["name"] == "M'lady" &&  $_POST["passwort"] == "lol") {
    $_SESSION["name"]  = "M'lady";
    $_SESSION["login"] = "ok";
    $extra = "website.php";
} 
else {
    $extra = "lol23.php?f-1";   
}
header("Location: http://localhost/canttellyouthat/website.php");

?>
```

website script:

```
<?php

    session_start(); 
    if (isset($_SESSION["login"]) && $_SESSION["login"] == "ok") {

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Geschützter Bereich</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo "<h1>Hi {$_SESSION['name']}</h1>"; 
?>
    <p><font color="FF0000"><font size="7">Wichtige Informationen</font></p>
    <p><a href="http://localhost/canttellyouthat/sorrydudes">Datenbank</p> 
    <p><a href="lol23.php"><font size="7">Ausloggen</font></p>
</body>
</html>

<?php

} else { 
    $host = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["HTTP_POST"]); 
    $uri  = rtrim(dirname(htmlspecialchars(["PHP_SELF"])), "/\\");
    $extra = "lol23.php"; 
    header("Location: http://localhost/lol23.php"); 
}

?>
```

Comment: code is messed. and too much of extra code

Comment: You have a unconditioned `header("Location: http://localhost/canttellyouthat/website.php");` in your `new 2.php` file. That means no matter what, location `http://localhost/canttellmethat/website.php` is bound to open.

Comment: _And I can't find any errors in my script._ Then you are just not looking very hard. There are **plenty there** to find if you just look

Comment: did you ever "log out"? Once you've logged in successfully, you have no way of invalidating the login credentials, and `$_SESSION['login']` will ALWAYS be `ok`.

Comment: @NijrajGelani and how can you change that? i'm new to php, so this is giving me troubles

Comment: @MarcB Yes I've logged put. I then go pack to the other php site, of whom script I've posted here.

Comment: @Abdulla And how is the code messed? Could you please explain that?

Comment: I think you meant to put `header("Location: http://localhost/$extra");` because you are setting the value of `$extra` to different php files based on a condition, but then you have a redirect hardcoded to only one file.

Comment: Could we see the code for the logout script? If not, could you tell us if it has a `session_destroy()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, you are using `location` without any if condition. Try change your code `new2.php` to:

```
<?php

session_start();
$host  = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
$uri   = rtrim(dirname(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])), "/\\");    

if (isset($_POST["name"]) && $_POST["name"] == "M'lady" &&  $_POST["passwort"] == "lol") {
    $_SESSION["name"]  = "M'lady";
    $_SESSION["login"] = "ok";
    header("Location: http://localhost/canttellyouthat/website.php"); 
} 
else {
    header("Location: http://localhost/canttellyouthat/lol23.php?f-1");   
}

?>
```